# ActiveRecord: searchable concern

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

### Problem

Suppose I have two models, both of which have a `name` field:

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Teacher < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

Now I want to find all the students and teachers who has the name 'Joe'. What I think to do:

```
name = 'Joe'
Student.where(name: name) + Teacher.where(name: name)
```

But things get ugly when I add other type of models which has also a `name` field and I want to search them:

```
name = 'Joe'
Student.where(name: name) + Teacher.where(name: name) + Manager.where(name: name) + ...
```

### Question

Is there a better way to do this? Ideally what I would like to do, define a module `Person` and then just:

```
Person.where(name: name)
```

**Note**: Changing the schema is not possible for other reasons.

Answer (score 0):

The solution may be to define your data models in a way that will lend themselves to this type of query. If you truly need to work on all "people" by name perhaps you should have a Person data model with roles or an attribute to define what "type" of person they are.

Comment: Thanks but this is not possible for other reasons.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track when you talk about defining a `Person` module. Look into [database normalization](http://www.studytonight.com/dbms/database-normalization.php) to get an idea of how best to define your models.

Since teachers and students are both people, but have different roles, you should store both of them in the same model, but add a field which allows you to select *just* the teachers or *just* the students. Something like this (in pseudo-code):

```
Person
    :name (string)
    :role (string)
```

With this, you can write queries like "find all people named John who have the role of teacher", or "find all people named Sue with any role".

With this kind of model, you'd need to enforce values on that role field so that people couldn't type anything they wanted - otherwise, you'd end up with some records that say 'student' and others that say 'classmate', for example. (You could take that a step further and store roles within a separate table, but that's another discussion!)

Comment: Changing the schema is not possible for other reasons.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use inheritance with rails, you do it like this:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  # shared person methods
end

class Student < Person
end

class Teacher < Person
end
```

You have to also have a table named `persons` with a column named `type`(string).

After this your students and teachers are going to be in `persons` table (you can delete original tables).

And you can query all students and persons with `Person.where(name: name)` and will include all students and teachers. And you can do `Student.all` to get only students, like a regular model.

Comment: Changing the schema is not possible for other reasons.